# Are CSS and html preinstalled on windows 10? If not, how do I install them

Tags: html, css, installation

I want to know, how I install html and CSS on windows 10. I can't find any tutorials on yt or google.
I'm beginning to think they are already preinstalled, I just want to make sure.
Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

HTML and CSS are both directly compiled in the browser itself. So it doesn't matter what version of windows you have. What you need is a web browser, like Chrome, Mozilla and Safari that supports HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

HTML & CSS are not languages computed by a computer, they are used in browsers. Every browser supports them but to different levels. If you want a HTML/CSS editor try VS Code, free and lightweight but fast as anything

Answer (score 1):

They are not "installed" in a computer. They are processed by any browser. If you have unclear what are they just follow this little explanation.

There are three main languages used to build a website:

- HTML: is a markup language used to create the skeleton of a layout.
- CSS: is a stylesheet language that describes the style of the elements in the web page.
- JavaScript: is a programming language in charge of making a website interactive, managing the user interaction with the layout components.

This is taken from an article I published on my blog about "What does a Front End do". You could read it [here](https://www.flaco.dev/blog/what-does-a-front-end-developer-do).

Cheers,
flaco.dev